# Serializer will not return all values in the model

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

When I create a post request with json ex.

```
{
    "title":"test",
    "company" : "test",
    "location" :"test",
    "link" :"http://www.google.com/1"
}
```

The response I recieve is:

```
{"id":538,"link":"http://www.google.com/1"}
```

Why are not all of my fields saving to the database?

I've changed  fields = '__all__' to fields = ('title', 'company', 'location', 'link') but I get an error:

> TypeError at /api/listings/ Object of type TextField is not JSON
>   serializable

```
from django.db import models

# Model:

class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=100,blank=True),
    company = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=True),
    location = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=True),
    link = models.URLField(max_length=250, unique=True)

#------------------------------------------------
from rest_framework import serializers
from listings.models import Listing


#Listing Serializer:

class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = '__all__'

#------------------------------------------------
from listings.models import Listing
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .serializers import ListingSerializer

#Listing Viewset:
class ListingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Listing.objects.all()
    #.objects.all().delete()
    permissions_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = ListingSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving my issue by creating a new project with the same app setup. I am assuming there was some issue with the initial migration of the app model.